# removing shared memories with ipcrm

Tags: linux, ipcs

I'm allocating some shared Memories and Message Queues with specific perm "644".

Removing them manually is a hard work so I want to know how can I remove all the rows with that specific perm 644.

e.g

------ Shared Memory Segments --------
key        shmid      owner      perms      bytes      nattch     status
0x00000000 0          benny      600        33554432   2          dest
0x00000000 229377     benny      644        52         0

------ Semaphore Arrays --------
key        semid      owner      perms      nsems

------ Message Queues --------
key        msqid      owner      perms      used-bytes   messages
0x2731af4c 262144     benny      644        840          30
0x0756d9c1 294913     benny      644        16380        585
0x2d1b2cc7 327682     benny      644        0            0
0x343dccc1 360451     benny      644        0            0

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a script to do it e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash

m=`ipcs -m | grep -w 644 | cut -d' ' -f2`
for i in $m
do
        echo removing shm id $i
        ipcrm -m $i
done

s=`ipcs -s | grep -w 644 | cut -d' ' -f2`
for i in $s
do
        echo removing sem id $i
        ipcrm -s $i
done

q=`ipcs -q | grep -w 644 | cut -d' ' -f2`
for i in $q
do
        echo removing queue id $i
        ipcrm -q $i
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ipcs -a | awk '{ \
  if ($3=="Memory")    ARG="-m"; \
  if ($3=="Semaphore") ARG="-s"; \
  if ($3=="Message")   ARG="-m"; \
  if ($4=="644")      system ("ipcrm "ARG" "$2""); \
  }'
```